# How to write a simple HTTP server in Haskell using Network.HTTP.receiveHTTP

Tags: http, haskell

The module [`Network.HTTP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.1.1/doc/html/Network-HTTP.html)
exposes the functions `receiveHTTP` and `respondHTTP` which I'd like to use for a very basic web server. I wrote a stub that just waits for clients:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Network.HTTP
import Network
import Control.Monad

main = withSocketsDo $ do
  socket <- listenOn $ PortNumber 8080
  forever $ do
    (handle, host, port) <- accept socket
    print (host, port)
```

Here `accpet` gives me a `Handle`, and now I can't figure out how to use a `Handle` with `receiveHTTP`.

I found [an example](http://lstephen.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/a-simple-haskell-web-server/) with Google, but it is from 2008 and does not work anymore. And I was not able to port it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't directly answer this, but you might be able to find some helpful examples with [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch).

Answer (score 8):

You can do this, but I really think you shouldn't. `HTTP` can act as a server, but is designed to be used client side. I Googled a little and I can't find any examples of someone actually using `respondHTTP`. If you're doing client side HTTP in 2016 use [`http-conduit`](https://www.stackage.org/package/http-conduit). On the server side, [`warp`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-6.3/package/warp-3.2.6) or something that depends upon it is probably what you want.

Nevertheless, here's the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.3 --install-ghc runghc --package HTTP
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Network.HTTP
import Network.Socket
import Network.URI

main = do
  lsock <- socket AF_INET Stream defaultProtocol
  bind lsock (SockAddrInet 8080 iNADDR_ANY)
  listen lsock 1
  forever $ do
    (csock, _) <- accept lsock
    hs <- socketConnection "" 8080 csock
    req <- receiveHTTP hs
    case req of
      Left _ -> error "Receiving request failed"
      Right (Request {..}) -> if uriPath rqURI == "/"
                            then do
                              respondHTTP hs $
                                Response (2,0,0) "OK" [] "Hello HTTP"
                              Network.HTTP.close hs
                            else do
                              respondHTTP hs $
                                Response (4,0,4) "Not found" [] "Nothing here"
                              Network.HTTP.close hs
```

The above uses Stack's support for shebang scripts. `chmod +x` it or run it with `stack foo.hs`.

The `Network` module is deprecated. Always use `Network.Socket` if you need a socket API. For something higher level, use [`connection`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-6.3/package/connection-0.2.5).

You do the normal POSIX socket thing, then convert the connected socket to a `HandleStream` with `socketConnection` and run `respondHTTP` and `receiveHTTP` on it. `socketConnection` is a weird function. The first two parameters are a hostname and a port which AFAICT aren't used when running a server.

I used the `RecordWildCards` extension. It lets me write `Right (Request {..})` in a pattern and have all the fields of the record in scope on the right hand side.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it expects you to use [the `accept` function from `Network.Socket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.3.0.3/doc/html/Network-Socket.html#v%3aaccept) instead of `Network`? That gives you a `Socket` instead of a `Handle`, which you should be able to convert to a form that `receiveHTTP` can use.

Normally a `Handle` would be nicer to work with directly, but here the HTTP library is taking care of it for you so it expects the lower-level interface instead.

**EDIT:** After looking at it a bit further, it seems the `socketConnection` function in `Network.TCP` does what you need. The funny part is it's actually making the socket into a `Handle` internally before it reads from it, but doesn't seem to provide a way to read from an externally-provided `Handle`. The string parameter to the function is supposed to be the name of the remote host, but it looks like that's merely kept for reference; it's not actually initiating a connection to that host or anything.